# M2Crypto.rsa privat key components

Tags: python, components, rsa, private-key, m2crypto

Can anybody tell me, how to get p,q,dp,dq and u component of rsa private key?
loading of the key:

```
string = open(keyfile,"rb").read();
bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(string);
rsa = RSA.load_key_bio(bio);
```

what shall i do next?

Answer (score 0):

`M2Crypto` does not support reading the rsa parameters directly, sorry.

you can kind of get e (public exponend) and n (modulus) from `res.pub()` (kind of, because the first bytes are not part of it).

the `Crypto` API on the other hand supports reading more parameters:

```
string = open(keyfile,"rb").read()
import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA
crsa = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.importKey(string)
print(crsa.n, crsa.e, crsa.d, crsa.p, crsa.q, crsa.u)
```